# Triggering a lambda from SNS using cloud-formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

Triggering a lambda from SNS using cloud-formation?

Answer (score 14):

What we do is that we don't point sns to an unqualified lambda, rather we point it to a lambda-alias. Basically, create a lambda, and then create an alias, use sns to point to the lambda-alias.

When you have new code for lambda (your ci/cd can do the following), update lambda function code, create a new lambda version, and repoint your alias to the new version. This way you sns doesn't have to change at all with new lambda code drops.

```
Resources: 
  AwsServerlessExpressFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: mylambda
      Description: mylambda 
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Handler: index.handler
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 60
      Role: !Ref LambdaExecutionRoleArn

  AwsServerlessExpressFunctionAlias:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref AwsServerlessExpressFunction
      FunctionVersion: '$LATEST'
      Name: live

  SNSTopic: 
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties: 
      DisplayName: mysnstopic
      TopicName: mysnstopic
      Subscription:  
      - 
        Endpoint: !Ref AwsServerlessExpressFunctionAlias
        Protocol: lambda

  LambdaInvokePermission: 
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties: 
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn:  !Ref SNSTopic 
      FunctionName: !Ref AwsServerlessExpressFunctionAlias
```

Comment: If you use cloudformation to update your stack, every updates will update the sns and lambda together. In such a case, I think a Lambda Alias is not necessary?

Answer (score 9):

You should not forget to add `LambdaFunctionPermission` to allow using of the SNS topic.

This is resource part of the Cloud Formation template in yaml:

```
Resources:
  SNSTopic: 
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties: 
      DisplayName: sns-topic-for-lambda
      TopicName: sns-topic-for-lambda
      Subscription:  
      - Endpoint: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
        Protocol: lambda

  LambdaFunctionPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
      Principal: sns.amazonaws.com

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use events to set up the trigger.

```
  lambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: 
      ------
      Events:
        SNS1:
          Type: SNS
          Properties:
            Topic:
              Ref: SNSTopic1
  SNSTopic1:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Topic'
```

Ref: Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless_app.html#serverless_app_resources

Comment: This should be topic ARN and not the Ref.
https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#sns

Comment: ref is for referencing a variable.

Comment: I know but if you had gone through the link you would've seen that the topic "ARN" is required. Nevertheless, just checked that both "Ref" and "Fn::GetAtt" returns the ARN of the topic. So it would still work out for SNS topic but ref is not equal to ARN's for every resource. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html

Comment: idea is to pass ARN as a parameter, as it is kind of static resource, this is just an example. its up to you to use it.

Comment: You can pass ARN as a parameter using Fn:GetAtt <Resource Name>, Ref: and Fn:GetAtt produces different values depending on the resource. As I mentioned before, in case of SNS Topic both Ref: and Fn:GetAtt provides the same value, so it works in this case, but Ref wouldn't work for every resource when ARN is required.

Comment: Is this 'Events' section deprecated? I don't see it in the latest Lambda cloudformation documentation. Maybe use Lambda permission instead?