# How to increase the AWS lambda to lambda connection timeout or keep the connection alive?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, timeout, boto3, connection-timeout

I am using boto3 lambda client to invoke a lambda_S from a lambda_M. My code looks something like

```
cfg = botocore.config.Config(retries={'max_attempts': 0},read_timeout=840, 
                             connect_timeout=600) # tried also by including the , 
                                                  # region_name="us-east-1"
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', config=cfg) # even tried without config
invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke  (
                                          FunctionName=lambda_name,                                      
                                          InvocationType='RequestResponse',                                                                          
                                          Payload=json.dumps(request)
                                        )
```

Lambda_S is supposed to run for like 6 minutes and I want lambda_M to be still alive to get the response back from lambda_S but lambda_M is timing out, after giving a CW message like
"Failed to connect to proxy URL: http://aws-proxy..."

I searched and found someting like configure your HTTP client, SDK, firewall, proxy or operating system to allow for long connections with timeout or keep-alive settings. But the issue is I have no idea how to do any of these with lambda. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you increased the default 5min timeout to say 10 or max 15mins? It's in Lambda > Configuration > Timeout

Comment: Hi  Adil Hindistan
yes sure my lambda time out is 900 sec. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure which doc you looked, maybe link it here? Also, how about using an sns topic instead of waiting? Can't you for example have lambda_S send an sns msg instead of returning something when done, and then sns topic triggers your lambda_m?

Comment: Thank you so much Adil for a great suggestion. Kindly share the link you mentioned.

Comment: sorry I think I was not clear. You said "I searched and found", I was referring to that.
Also using sns as the messenger is pretty common pattern. I will create an example as an answer when I have time for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this a bit differently. Lambdas charge you by second, so in general you should avoid waiting in them. One way you can do that is create an sns topic and use that as the messenger to trigger another lambda.

Workflow goes like this.

SNS-A -> triggers Lambda-A
SNS-B -> triggers lambda-B

So if you lambda B wants to send something to A to process and needs the results back, from lambda-B you send a message to SNS-A topic and quit.

SNS-A triggers lambda, which does its work and at the end sends a message to SNS-B

SNS-B triggers lambda-B.

AWS has example documentation on what policies you should put in place, [here is one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html).

I don't know how you are automating the deployment of native assets like SNS and lambda, assuming you will use cloudformation,

1. you create your AWS::Lambda::Function
2. you create AWS::SNS::Topic
   and in its definition, you add 'subscription' property and point it to you lambda.
   So in our example, your SNS-A will have a subscription defined for lambda-A
3. lastly you grant SNS permission to trigger the lambda: AWS::Lambda::Permission

When these 3 are in place, you are all set to send messages to SNS topic which will now be able to trigger the lambda.

You will find SO answers to questions on how to do this cloudformation ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898995/triggering-a-lambda-from-sns-using-cloud-formation)) but you can also read up on AWS cloudformation documentation.

If you are not worried about automating the stuff and manually tests these, then aws-cli is your friend.